# "Login incorrect" error on Raspberry Pi 4 during initial setup of Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, login, raspberrypi

I'm doing the initial setup of Ubuntu on Raspberry Pi. Followed the tutorial step by step from the official site.

When it asks to login, the initial login details are entered are as follows:

```
ubuntu login: ubuntu
Password: ubuntu
```

But I keep on getting:

```
Login incorrect
```

I have tried the following login details too, but to no avail:

```
ubuntu login: pi
Password: raspberry
```

Here is the error I get:

[image: Error on the screen]

After a couple of minutes of getting the `Login incorrect` error, the screen resets and only `ubuntu login:` stays on it.

I also tried installing Ubuntu 20.04.4, hoping to resolve the issue, but it still persists.

Comment: I can think of only two reasons. 1) the password isn't being entered correctly. For example, perhaps the keyboard is a different layout? Or you are miskeying? 2) You made a mistake flashing the SD card. Was there already another installation on the SD card? Maybe you chose the wrong image? You might want to format the SD card and start over.  Is this the tutorial you are following?: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi

Comment: Plug it in, wait some time (I'd try 15 minutes), and then try logging in. I forgot why, but on the first time you have to wait a while before it works IIRC. In theory, only a few minutes. But you could try waiting, say, 15 minutes after boot, and then try

Comment: @Nmath For the first reason, I don't think that's possible since I can see what I have typed for login, and writing exactly the same for the password (which I have tried like 100 times now). For the second I formatted the memory card properly and then installed added the image using Raspberry Pi imager v1.7.1. So not sure if that's the issue again. Yes, I'm using the following tutorial that you've metioned

Comment: @cocomac I've waited like an hour but no result :( I'm trying to install a different version of Ubuntu to see if it works

Comment: Did you read the note that says "During your first boot a tool called cloud-init is doing configuration. WAIT for it to finish before trying to log in. It typically takes less than 2 minutes but there is a break between the log-in prompt and cloud-init completing. If you interrupt the process you have to start again. You’ll know it’s done when it outputs some more lines after the log-in prompt has appeared."?

Comment: @cocomac yes ofcourse, I waited for all the lines to appear. I believe those lines stay there and don't go away. I'm re-installing as we speak, this time I will wait for at least 20 minutes before attempting my first login

Comment: update: The problem still persists, banging my head on the wall :D

Comment: You may want to download the image manually from https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi. Don't skip instructions to "verify your download". Then flash the image manually to your SD card.  I prefer [etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/), because the interface is painfully simple for flashing system images.  Finally, insert the SD card, and plug in the power.  Don't plug in anything else! You really do need to WAIT several minutes for it to initialize--  seriously just walk away, do something else, and come back to it later.

Comment: I have seen this with the raspberry pi imager tool, and it not capturing the password you typed in the imager tool. As a result, it missed one of your characters (similar to mentioned above) and it not doing it correctly.  I've also noticed it can have trouble with the ssh authorized_keys entry, and denying login.  I found I had to change to "ubuntu" as my default user and /slowly/ type the password and allow password auth for 22.02.3 to successfully image to my B+.  I have not affirmed that this is the only solution but a note.  +1 if you found it helped.